# BiCMOS voltage follower analysis help

Tags: emitter-follower, common-collector

I am looking to mathematically characterize the circuit shown before, consisting of two (MOSFET) current mirrors and a BJT (common collector or emitter follower?). I am stuck at the first current mirror (PMOS.)  I am a beginner at circuit analysis. I am doing a holistic reliability study (NBTI, HCI, electromigration, etc.,) so I think it would really help to understand the circuit's functionality. I was told that this circuit's functionality is so that you can deliver the same voltage and attach any input you want.

I have tried to reference Sedra and Smith's *Microelectronic Circuits*, but am sincerely lost in the sauce. Any input, thoughts or insight is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If I told you that it's a poor circuit for what you believe it does (what you were told), would it change your opinion about analysing it?

Comment: This circuit could be useful as temperature dependent guitar distortion module.

Comment: @andyaka it would not change my endeavor to analyze it. I was provided this by advisor, so I need to roll with it.

Comment: @jens haha I believe this is a joke.

Comment: The advise is flawed.